# extracting RGB from GIF image

Tags: c#, gif

I need to extract  RGB byte values of each pixel of a small GIF stored on a PC (16x16 pixels) as I need to send them to a LED display that accepts RGB 6 byte color code.

After opening the test file and converting it to a 1D byte array I get some byte values, but I am not sure if that decodes the GIF frame and as a result will return my desired pure 192 byte RGB array?

```
 'img = Image.FromFile("mygif.gif");               
  FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
  int frameCount = img.GetFrameCount(dimension);
  img.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, 0);
  gifarray = imageToByteArray(img);`

   //image to array conversion func.
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();

    }
```

Or maybe there is another method for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to get a 2d array containing the pixels:

```
//using System.Drawing;
Color[,] getPixels(Image image)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)image;
    Color[,] pixels = new Color[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];

    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            pixels[x, y] = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

    return pixels;
}
```

Using the data returned by this method, you can get each pixel's `R`, `G`, `B`, and `A` (each are a single byte) and do whatever you want with them.

If you want the end result to be a `byte[]` containing values like this: `{ R0, G0, B0, R1, G1, B1, ... }`, and the pixels need to be written to the `byte[]` in row-major order, then you do this:

```
byte[] getImageBytes(Image image)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)image;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(bmp.Width * bmp.Height) * 3]; // 3 for R+G+B

    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            bytes[x + y * bmp.Width + 0] = pixel.R;
            bytes[x + y * bmp.Width + 1] = pixel.G;
            bytes[x + y * bmp.Width + 2] = pixel.B;
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

You can then send the result of `getImageBytes` to your LED (assuming that that's how you're supposed to send images to it).

Comment: thanks, its exacly what i do and it works. i just assumed i can't treat GIF as a bitmap. the problem is i am loosing the option to cycle frames right now.

Comment: OK I get it, its just a simple cast from Image class to Bitmap and it can be done. issue closed, thanks for your replies

Comment: @PK If this is the right answer, then please mark it as so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your way will not decode it to raw RGB byte data. It will most likely output the same data that you loaded in the beginning (GIF encoded).

You will need extract the data pixel by pixel:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    Bitmap lbBMP = new Bitmap(imageIn);
    List<byte> lbBytes = new List<byte>();

    for(int liY = 0; liY < lbBMP.Height; liY++)
        for(int liX = 0; liX < lbBMP.Width; liX++)
        {
            Color lcCol = lbBMP.GetPixel(liX, liY);
            lbBytes.AddRange(new[] { lcCol.R, lcCol.G, lcCol.B });
        }

    return lbBytes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that gifs can have transparency.  Does the Windows codec send that through in the Color.A?

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't include that since the question said "RGB" and not "RGBA".

Comment: OK, it works. Thanks a lot, did not realize I can load GIF image as a bitmap. The drawback is that I can control the frames of a GIF image - I can only load the very first frame.